# how to shift value in dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like this, without z1, what i need is to add a column to DataFrame, so it will add column z1 and represent values as in the example, what it should do is to shift z value equally on 1 day before for the same Start date.

[image]
I was thinking it could be done with apply and lambda in pandas, but i`m not sure how to define lambda function

```
data = pd.read_csv("....")

data["Z"] = data[[
                "Start", "Z"]].apply(lambda x:
```

Comment: Why `564545` in the last row? Isn't supposed to be `56`? Because if you want the `z value equally on 1 day before for the same Start date.`, it would correspond to `32400000 2012-10-02` (row 7)  instead of `32400000 2012-10-01` (row 2).

Comment: yes, you`re correct, it`s a mistake in example given to me

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
#if not datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1 = df.groupby('start')['z'].shift(freq='1D',periods=1).reset_index()
print (pd.merge(df.reset_index(),df1, on=['start','date'], how='left', suffixes=('','1')))

        date  start       z        z1
0 2012-12-01    324  564545       NaN
1 2012-12-01    384    5555       NaN
2 2012-12-01    349     554       NaN
3 2012-12-02    855     635       NaN
4 2012-12-02    324      56  564545.0
5 2012-12-01    341      98       NaN
6 2012-12-03    324     888      56.0
```

EDIT:

Try find duplicates and `fillna` by `0`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df1 = df.groupby('start')['z'].shift(freq='1D',periods=1).reset_index()
df2 = pd.merge(df.reset_index(),df1, on=['start','date'], how='left', suffixes=('','1'))
mask = df2.start.duplicated(keep=False)
df2.ix[mask, 'z1'] = df2.ix[mask, 'z1'].fillna(0)
print (df2)
        date  start       z        z1
0 2012-12-01    324  564545       0.0
1 2012-12-01    384    5555       NaN
2 2012-12-01    349     554       NaN
3 2012-12-02    855     635       NaN
4 2012-12-02    324      56  564545.0
5 2012-12-01    341      98       NaN
6 2012-12-03    324     888      56.0
```

Comment: thats great, thanks! but how come using different data set i get NotImplementedError: Not supported for type Index

Comment: It looks likeyou forget dtetimeindex `df.set_index('date', inplace=True)`.

Comment: What is `print df.index` before `df1 = df.groupby('start')['z'].shift(freq='1D',periods=1).reset_index()` ?

Comment: i tried df['date']= pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['date']), format="%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: tells me that date doesnt match format, i checked data itself and nothing wrong with it

Comment: And how works `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")` ?

Comment: If it doest work, there is some wrong format. You can find it by `print  df[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d", errors='coerce').isnull()]`

Comment: oh, that works, great, but doesn`t somehow now count z1

Comment: because the first row in my dataset is 0, thats why

Comment: the first couple rows in Z are empty and some later too

Comment: what does df2.start.duplicated do?

Comment: It find all duplicated values in column `start` - see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html

Comment: it works perfect on data set in example but if for example try diiferent one, doest want to calculate

Comment: date                 start             z       0
0  2012-10-01      85580000       0     NaN
1  2012-10-01      38450000       0     NaN
2  2012-10-01      34960000       0     NaN
3  2012-10-01      34180000     999     NaN
4  2012-10-02      85580000     635       0
5  2012-10-02      32400000      56     NaN
6  2012-10-01      34180000      98     NaN
7  2012-10-01      34960000       5     NaN
8  2012-10-03      32400000     888      56
9  2012-10-04      34180000  866969     NaN
10 2012-10-03      34960000       1     NaN
11 2012-10-05      34180000    9855  866969

Comment: Maybe you need sort values first. See [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) - try `df = df.sort_values(by='start')`